# How can I make one piece of code for several structs?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, struct, coding-efficiency

I have 4 structs:

Computer,
Home,
Car,
Ship

I declared:

**1.** An array that can hold up to 5 types of computers.

**2.** An array that can hold up to 20 houses, each can have one computer.

**3.** An array that can hold up to 20 cars, each can have one computer.

**4.** An array that can hold up to 20 ships, each can have one computer.

This is the code:

```
struct Computer
{
    public string pcName;

    public string motherBoardName;
    public string graphicCardName;

    public int memorySize;
    public int numberOfDrivers;
}

struct Home
{
    public Computer pc;
    list of parameters for home... (int, byte, string, double)    
}

struct Car
{
    public Computer pc;
    list of parameters for a car... (int, byte, string, double)    
}

struct Ship
{
    public Computer pc;
    list of parameters for a ship... (int, byte, string, double)    
}

Computer[] pc = new Computer[5]; // 5 types of computers

Home[] home = new Home[20]; // Up to 20 houses
Car[] car = new Car[20]; // Up to 20 cars
Ship[] ship = new Ship[20]; // Up to 20 ships
```

I want to be able to set/get parameters for each one of the 5 computers in the pc array, and also for each one of the computers (pc) at home, car or a ship.

On my panel I have an editBox for each one of the pc parameters:

**pcName, motherBoardName, graphicCardName, memorySize, numberOfDrivers**

I have a "**Set**" and a "**Get**" buttons, and some few more controls (for example radioButtons) that let the user choose if he's setting or getting parameters for one of the 5 computers (in the computers array) or for a PC in one of the homes, one of the cars, or one of the ships.

**Now comes my main question:**

Can I somehow write a single piece of code that can Set a PC parameters for each one of them? (computer[5], home[20], car[20], ship[20]) and a single piece of code that can Get a PC parameters from each one of these arrays and show them on the panel?

Or must I write one function to set parameters for a PC, one that set parameters for a home pc, one for a car pc... so I will end up with 8 different functions for all the sets and gets?

I hope that my question is clear enough.

Waiting for your advice.
Thanks.

Comment: For a start, you should be using classes rather than structures.

Comment: OK, and then what? And how?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes", but I suspect that you're actually asking us to write it for you or teach you how, which is not the job of this site. If you don't know how to get and set properties then you need to spend more time learning the basics.

Comment: I know how to get and set properties, but I'm not sure how to write a single method that knows how to set/get PC parameters for each one of the classes (pc, home, car, ship). I just need a direction.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood what you're asking. You can't really write a single method that will take those different arrays but, if you use classes instead of structures, that's not a problem. You just write a method that takes an `IEnumerable<Computer>`  and get that from whatever source you have, e.g. `myShipArray.Select(s => s.Computer)`. Using classes, that will get the original `Computer` objects that you can then pass to a method that will modify them. If they were structures, you'd be getting copies. This is why structures should be immutable and mutable types should be classes.

Comment: Suggested Reading: [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct).

Comment: @Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp Thanks, I read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you should be using classes rather than structures. The behaviour of value types makes working with mutable structures tricky so structures should generally only be small, immutable types. You should be using classes with properties, rather than structures with fields.

We only need two of your types to demonstrate what you could/should do:

```cs
public class Computer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // ...
}

public class Home
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Computer Computer { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

You can then write a method that takes an `IEnumerable<Computer>` to modify any list of `Computer` objects.

```cs
private void ModifyComputers(IEnumerable<Computer> computers)
{
    foreach (var computer in computers)
    {
        // Use computer here.
    }
}
```

If you have a `Computer` array then you can pass that directly. If you have a `Home` array then you can get the `Computer` from each one using LINQ and pass the result.

```cs
Computer[] computers;
Home[] homes;

// ...

ModifyComputers(computers);
ModifyComputers(homes.Select(h => h.Computer));
```

That [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) method will take an enumerable list as an input, perform the specified transformation on each item and return an enumerable list containing the results. In that last line of code, the transformation is "get the `Computer` from the `Home`".

Actually, one point to note is that, because you're using arrays that may have `null` elements, the code above may throw a `NullReferenceException`. You would need to either change the method to account for `null`:

```cs
private void ModifyComputers(IEnumerable<Computer> computers)
{
    foreach (var computer in computers)
    {
        if (computer != null)
        {
            // Use computer here.
        }
    }
}
```

or make sure to not pass any `null` references:

```cs
Computer[] computers;
Home[] homes;

// ...

ModifyComputers(computers.Where(c => c != null));
ModifyComputers(homes.Where(h => h != null).Select(h => h.Computer));
```

If you go for the first option, you'd also need to account for `null` references in the `Home` array:

```cs
ModifyComputers(homes.Select(h => h?.Computer));
```

The `?.` operator will return `null` if the first operand is `null` where the `.` operator would throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks very much, I really appreciate it. I think that your code can be a good starting point for me, I just started reading about IEnumerable and how to use it.

Comment: @Programmerman, I made an important edit relating to `null` references.

Comment: Thanks very much, I saw your adding. I will sure try this, thanks a lot.